# How to index a 1D numpy array as if it is a matrix with 1 row?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a 1D numpy array like:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
```

And I would like to index this `a` like (as if it's a 1 by 5 matrix, and `a[0,2]` would be equal to 3):

```
a[0,2]

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-34-2fc0526218b3>", line 1, in <module>
    a[0,1]

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

I know in MATLAB it's possible, but how to do that in Python? The reason that I need this is coz that `a` is dynamically generated, sometimes it's a 1D array, sometimes it's a nD array. And I need a unified way of indexing in my loop.

Comment: What if it's a 3D array?

Comment: I know for sure it will be 2D, since my original data is a bunch of multi-dimensional data points each with a partition label. And I'm trying to extract the data points with the same label, some label may only have 1 data point, some have many data points.

Comment: If you know for sure it will be 2D, you shouldn't sometimes get a 1D array.

Comment: Sorry I meant at least 1D and at most 2D.

Comment: MATLAB is always 2d or higher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`np.atleast_2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.atleast_2d.html) to promote 1D arrays to 2D:

```
a = np.atleast_2d(a)
```

If you put this inside of your loop then you can henceforth treat all `a`s as 2D (or higher-dimensional) arrays.

---

For example,

```
In [103]: a1 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
In [105]: np.atleast_2d(a1)
Out[107]: array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
```

while higher-dimensional arrays are unchanged:

```
In [104]: a2 = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
In [108]: np.atleast_2d(a2)
Out[108]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

Comment: Well this is handy!

Answer (score 1):

Use `.reshape` and pass `-1` as the second argument:

```
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> a = a.reshape(1, -1)
>>> a[0,2]
3
```

Note, if you are expecting any type of `ndarray`, then this might not be what you want:

```
>>> arr = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
>>> arr
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
>>> arr.reshape(1, -1)
array([[1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

So you *may* need to add a conditional check:

```
>>> if a.ndim < 2:
...     a = a.reshape(1, -1)
...
>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use these as well:

```
In [7]: a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

# make it as row vector of shape (1, 5)
In [8]: a = a[np.newaxis, :]

In [9]: a[0,2]
Out[9]: 3


# another approach using `None`    
In [10]: a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

# make it as row vector of shape (1, 5)
In [11]: a = a[None, :]

In [12]: a[0, 2]
Out[12]: 3
```

When you use [`np.newaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) or `None` once, a new axis is added; Note that you've assign this to your original array to make modification to the final array.